# Sum up only concurrent rows

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to sum up concurrent rows so

```
Tool     State       Duration  Start_DT  End_Dt
ToolA    Enabled     10        09:00     09:10
ToolA    Idle        5         09:10     09:15
ToolA    Enabled     10        09:15     09:25
ToolA    Enabled     15        09:25     09:40
ToolA    Disable     7         09:40     09:47
ToolA    Enabled     3         09:47     09:50
ToolA    Enabled     5         09:50     09:55
ToolA    Enabled     10        09:55     10:05
ToolB    Idle        2         09:00     09:02
ToolB    Idle        7         09:02     09:09
ToolB    Disabled    10        09:09     09:19
```

Would become

```
Tool     State       Duration  Start_DT  End_Dt
ToolA    Enabled     10        09:00     09:10
ToolA    Idle        5         09:10     09:15
ToolA    Enabled     25        09:15     09:40
ToolA    Disable     7         09:40     09:47
ToolA    Enabled     18        09:47     10:05
ToolB    Idle        9         09:00     09:09
ToolB    Disabled    10        09:09     09:19
```

These all come from the one table.
I have used functions to identify when a rows State matches the previous or next row.
I think I need some kind of identifier to aggregate these.
I was thinking of a cumulative sum but don't see how I can keep it to only those matching rows.
Can I put a clause in a cum sum to stop when row_match = 0?
Any help is appreciated.

```
select Tool, State, duration, start_dt, 
,case when state = lead(state) over (partition by tool order by start_dt)
or state = lead(state) over (partition by tool order by start_dt)
then 1 else 0 end row_match
from tbl_tool_state_times;
```

Comment: That's the ideal task for match_recognize

Comment: Hadn't heard of match_recognize till just now. I will read up on it - thank you

Comment: My work haven't upgraded to 12c yet. Is there an 11 workaround?

Answer (score 2):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  I would suggest the difference of row numbers and aggregation:

```
select tool, state, sum(duration), min(start_dt), max(end_dt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tool order by start_dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by tool, state order by start_dt) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by tool, state, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Note:  This assumes that the there are no gaps in the times for the records.  That assumption is quite consistent with your sample data.

How this works is a bit tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference between the row numbers identifies adjacent rows with the same state.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are not on 12c but maybe in future you can implement it using match_recognise on Oracle 12c :

```
SELECT TOOL, STATE,  SUM(DURATION), MIN(START_DT) START_DT, MAX(END_DT) END_DT FROM (
    select * from Table_match_recognize
match_recognize (
 partition by tool order by  Start_DT
  measures
    match_number() as mno,
    classifier() as cls
  all rows per match
  pattern (  dont_match*  MATCH1*  dont_match*) 
  define
    MATCH1 as STATE = next(STATE) or state = prev(state),
    DONT_MATCH as STATE <> PREV(STATE) and state <> next(state)
    
) MR ) GROUP BY TOOL, STATE, MNO, CLS ORDER BY TOOL, START_DT;
```